# Binary File Processing - fseek() to a certain field inside a struct

Tags: c, file-io, padding, memory-alignment, fseek

```
struct good {

int ID;
char name[20];
int quantity;
float cost;
}

struct good article;

fseek(hw2, f*sizeof(struct good) + sizeof(article.ID) + sizeof(article.name), SEEK_SET);
```

Does the value of the parameter sizeof() + sizeof() + sizeof() yield the expected value: the index of the first byte in the quantity field? When I try to write to the field using this file position control statement, reading back the record, I find that it wasn't written properly.

I think it's all about padding and memory alignment.

P.S.:

Clearer code sample:

```
struct good {
short int ID;
char name[20];
int quantity = 0;
float cost = 0;
};
struct good article;
article.ID = 2;                 
article.name = "Maisara";       //These two fields are already filled, I want to write only to the coming field
article.quantity = 7;   

fseek(hw2, f*sizeof(struct good) + sizeof(article.ID) + sizeof(article.name), SEEK_SET);
fwrite(&article.quantity, sizeof(article.quantity), 1, hw2);
```

Comment: What are you trying to read and write? Can you post the code for both?

Comment: You want [`offsetof`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offsetof).

Comment: Why do you want to fseek here? You can simply jump the pointer by incrementing it?

Comment: There are number of unclear doubts here:: where does "hw2" points to? What is "f" in "f * sizeof(struct good)" ?

Comment: 1. hw2 points to an open file in the rb+ mode.

Comment: 2. f is a constant, a for loop counter.

Comment: Does using the increment differ from using fseek concerning the padding added by the compiler?

Answer (score 0):

When you read or write out your struct, do not do any formatting to it. I.e.:

```
write ( fd, (void*) article, sizeof(article) );
```

If you don't want to waste space on disk and increase portability when writing out the struct you can create your struct with the __packed keyword (or similar, compiler specific) and that will instruct the compiler to not optimize the struct in terms of memory alignment.

You can also mmap your struct.